# Table grid using Div in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to create a table grid using DIV (HTML & CSS only). I almost got into and still got some issues. I attached the sample image. I want the grid should be the same like this sample image. I attached the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/Hv3V4/) of what I created so far. Could you help somebody that what am doing and how can I improve to finish the table as same as the image?

### HTML:

```
<div class="containerDiv">

  <div class="rowDivHeader">
    <div class="cellDivHeader">Recommendation</div>
    <div class="cellDivHeader">Typical savings</div>
    <div class="cellDivHeader">Improved SAP</div>
    <div class="cellDivHeader">Improved EI</div>
    <div class="cellDivHeader">Indicative cost</div>
    <div class="cellDivHeader">Include</div>
    <div class="cellDivHeader lastCell">Removal Reason</div>
  </div>

  <div class="rowDiv">
    <div class="cellDiv">Room-in-roof-insulation</div>
    <div class="cellDiv">93.0</div>
    <div class="cellDiv">F : 29</div>
    <div class="cellDiv">B : 89</div>
    <div class="cellDiv">£1,500 - £2,700</div>
    <div class="cellDiv">Checkbox</div>
    <div class="cellDiv lastCell">Textbox</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.containerDiv {
  border: 1px solid #3697f6;
  width: 100%;
}

.rowDivHeader {
  border: 1px solid #668db6;
  background-color: #336799;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.rowDiv {
  border: 1px solid #668db6;
  background-color: #cee6fe;
}

.cellDivHeader {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  display: table-cell;
  width:12%;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.cellDiv {
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  display: table-cell;
  width:10%;
  padding-right: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.lastCell {
  border-right: none;
}
```

### sample image

[image: Sample Table Grid Image]

Comment: "I want to create a table grid using DIV" - why? You should be using a TABLE.

Comment: "I like to have a first and last column of the width would more than the middle of the div's." Wuuut?

Comment: Hi, that's my task to finish to create a table grid by using div.

Comment: @Amberlamps Sorry, wrongly added the line. Sorry. I edited

Comment: Ok, everybody hate tables, they are not good when you use them in whole website, as markup. This does not mean that you won't have to use table anymore. When I have doubt i am thinking that if i can insert the data in an excel sheet. In your case i guess a <table> with <thead> & stuff will help you to get exact what you need.

Comment: For this task, the main reason is am going to use this grid in ruby on rails project. By using table grid is not come inside the <form></form>. For example, if you see the sample image, the form method closed above the grid.

Comment: This is tabular data and therefore should be one of the times you should be using tables!

Comment: @Vinay - If the form is not wrapping the table, that's the real problem, and the one you should be asking about here, not trying to work around it by marking up tabular data with div elements.

Comment: am a newbie.... confusing to get the results.. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display:table-row` to the row div i.e `.rowDivHeader & .rowDiv`

& `display:table` to the main div `.containerDiv`

```
.containerDiv {
  border: 1px solid #3697f6;
  width: 100%; display:table
}    
.rowDivHeader {
      border: 1px solid #668db6;
      background-color: #336799;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold; display:table-row
    }
    .rowDiv {
      border: 1px solid #668db6;
      background-color: #cee6fe;
      display:table-row
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hv3V4/4/)**

Comment: Hi sowmya, If i using form method with your css, the header is fine but all the columns show in the first column(Recommendation) and the remaining columns are empty.

Comment: Seriously not getting your point. http://jsfiddle.net/Hv3V4/5/ check this. is this what u want?

Comment: hi, sorry. Your code is working fine and I implemented in my project as well. When i get this table inside the form in ruby on rails, all the columns are placed into the first column and the other columns are empty.

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment, have a look at this.. http://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/Hv3V4/6/

Comment: why dont to use the form to the entire table. like this http://jsfiddle.net/Hv3V4/7/

Comment: Because, i am using each do statement in rails. So if i using form for the entire table then each row would have the header.

Comment: Any idea, that we could use the form only for the data's(rowDiv) rather than the entire table? Thanks